# Get js classname inside super method of child in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a parent class in JS that has some properties of which some are based on the class name of the child classes:

**ParentClass.js**

```
export default class ParentClass {

    constructor(className) {

        this.className = className;
        this.classNameLowerCase = className.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

In a child class I extend the parent class and use `super()` for the constructor invocation where I will pass the class name of the child class.

**ChildClass.js**

```
import ParentClass from  "./ParentClass.js";


class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    constructor() {
        super("ChildClass");
    }
}
```

As you can see the child class is called **ChildClass** and I also pass this name as a string in `super()`. I prefer to get the class name of the child class with a funtion (without havind to repeat myself). Without using `super()` I could use `this.constructor.name` to get the name of the class, but inside `super()` `this` is not allowed and neither anywhere before the parentclass constructor invocation.

How can I get the child class name to use as an argument inside `super()`?

Comment: What is the use of the childClass name ? In Js you can declare several classes with the same name, you wouldn't know which one is your instance using. you better rely on using `instanceof` than doing check on "class names".

Comment: I am using it for a number of properties (strings) that are defined by the childClass name and are needed in several places.

Comment: @Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant, several classes with the same name? Can you show an example?

Comment: for example you copy ChildClass.js in ChildClass2.js without changing the code. Now `var Class1 = require('childClass.js'); var Class2 = require('childClass2.js')`. You can create instances with `new Class1()` and `new Class2()`, if you rely on `myobj.className` you will think they are using the same class. Using `myobj instanceof Class1` will work only with myobj is created with Class1.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, oh, sorry, i thought you mean that in JS you really can declare several classes with the same name, and it is not related to the current question. Ok, thanks for explanation. 
@DirkJ.Faber, what's the use of user defined className? Why can't you rely solely on `this.constructor.name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to put the functionality into the parent constructor - if no `className` is passed, check `this.constructor.name`:

```js
class ParentClass {
    constructor(className) {
        if (!className) {
            className = this.constructor.name;
        }
        this.className = className;
        this.classNameLowerCase = className.toLowerCase();
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const c = new ChildClass();
console.log(c.className);
```